# Why is my DBCP connection pool running out of connections?

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, connection-pooling

I have developed Java application using connection pooling (DBCP) with Sql Server 2005. In my configuration file I have `MaxActive="500"` but in some cases it will exceed more then 500 connects.  Why?  And database is slow that time.

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/tm4u"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX;databaseName=XX;User=abc;Password=son;selectMethod=cursor"
    username="abc"
    password="son"
    autoReconnect="true"
    maxActive="500"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    logAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    maxIdle="10"
    />
```

Comment: It is all depending on which connection pool implementation you are using.  Can you mention which one you are using?

Comment: See this link.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBCP-379  It seems it is a bug in DBCP

Comment: Please edit your question and show us some of the code that actually uses the connections.  Where are they allocated and where are they closed?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, do you close the connections that were opened? By doing this the connections will be returned to the pool and re-used. There should be no performance degradation in this case. However, if we need more than 500 active connections, some of them will have to wait.

Also see other questions on SO related to pooling.